# (Django) Как записать новый ключ в форме ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Мне нужно чтобы при создании нового вопроса он был связан именно с этим тестом, но я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы в форму можно было записать новое значение, а не выбрать из уже существующих.

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    objects = None
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class TestQuestion(models.Model):
    objects = None
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class AddTest(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = '__all__'


class AddQuestion(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TestQuestion
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def addtest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = AddTest(request.POST)
        form2 = AddQuestion(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            try:
                Test.objects.create(**form1.cleaned_data)
                TestQuestion.objects.create(**form2.cleaned_data)

            except:
                form1.add_error(None, 'Ошибка форма 1')
                form2.add_error(None, 'Ошибка форма 2')


    else:
        form1 = AddTest()
        form2 = AddQuestion()

    data = {'title': 'Добавление теста',
            'menu': menu,
            'form1': form1,
            'form2': form2
            }

    return render(request, 'testsystem/addtest.html', data)
```

Скрин страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вам вообще в таком случае foreignkey?

Comment: @strawdog, мне нужно связать вопросы к тесту с определенным тестом. Я только учусь и подумал, что это хороший вариант. Если вы можете предложить как сделать, я буду рад узнать. Но думаю все равно стоит поработать и с этим типом связи, для практики.

Comment: не совсем понятно - чем отличается тест от "вопросов к тесту"? это не одно и то же ли? или  у вас может быть несколько блоков вопросов к одному тесту? и вам нужно, чтобы **помимо** выбора существующих тестов можно было добавить новый?

Comment: @strawdog , да все верно. В тесте может быть множество вопросов. И пользователь(преподаватель) должен моч добавить новый тест с впоросами.